# Are contributions to 401k outside of payroll pre-tax?

Tags: united-states, 401k, contribution

Between my payroll deductions for 401k and my employer's contribution, I don't get to my $18,500 + $6,000 catch-up limit for 2018.
If I put money into the 401k account from my own funds/savings to reach my limit, will that give me a tax advantage? Will it also reduce my taxable income?

[This is a similar question](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/100687/if-i-have-a-401k-for-a-partial-year-can-i-still-contribute-the-maximum-amount) but I'm not clear from the answers if it reduces the taxable income.

Added: My 401k plan allows me to add my own money to it (I just did it using their online portal). My question is if that money that I add reduces my taxable income.

Comment: It sounds like you may want to contribute to an IRA, if you haven't already.

Answer (score 8):

It is not possible to put money into a 401k other than through payroll deductions. If your employer’s plan limits the amount you can put in, there’s nothing more you can do.

By the way, the employer’s contribution doesn’t count toward the $18,500 limit.

Comment: This isn't strictly true.  However the other ways probably don't apply to OP's situation.